# Clear the TEMP folder on shutdown

Tags: windows-xp, script, shutdown

I am following some instructions in *[More Ways To Speed Up Windows XP](http://www.connectedinternet.co.uk/2006/01/12/more-ways-to-speed-up-windows-xp/)* to help speed up my computer. One of those was to delete the `temp` folder on shutdown. Yet after I shutdown and then boot up, the script did not touch my `temp` folder, and I am unsure what's wrong. What should I change?

Here are the instructions I have:

```
1. Open Notepad and create a new file with the following entries:

RD /S /q “C:\Documents and Settings\"UserName without quotes”\Local Settings\
          History”
RD /S /q “C:\Documents and Settings\Default User\Local Settings\History”
RD /S /q “D:\Temp” <–”Deletes temp folder, type in the location of your temp 
                      folder”

2. Save the new file as anything you like, but it has to be a ‘.bat’ file,
   for example, `fastboot.bat` or `deltemp.bat`

3. Click ‘Start’ then ‘Run’

4. Type in ‘gpedit.msc’ and hit ‘OK’

5. Click on ‘Computer Configuration’ then ‘Windows Settings’

6. Double-click on ‘Scripts’ and then on ‘Shutdown’

7. Click ‘Add’ and find the batch file that you created and then press ‘OK’
```

I have followed these instructions, and I see where Windows says "Running Shutdown Script". Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you verify that your temp directory is in `D:\temp`?

Comment: @jonsca - That was the example, I changed the file path to my temp folder which is `C:\Documents and Settings\Lynda\Local Settings\Temp`

Comment: What happens when you run the batch file manually at a prompt?

Comment: @jonsca - I have not tried, how exactly do I run it at prompt?

Comment: Start up a `cmd` and change to whatever directory your `.bat` file is in.  Run it by typing the name without the `.bat`. (it may work if you include the ending, but I know for sure that it works if you don't)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than going through all this, which may be overkill to do it on a daily basis anyway, run something like [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/CCLEANER) every week or so to get rid of the temp files.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I figured it out though. When I ran it it kept telling me file path not found. What I realized is the folder was "hidden" and when I changed it from hidden to visible it worked like a charm.  Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted here somewhere, that if you ever go to install a program and the program installation fails, that you should disable wiping out the temporary folders at shutdown or startup.

I have been there and done that :-)  Very rarely, a program will bust itself out in the temp folders, then reboot the system to complete the instalation. Ahh, you know the rest.