# How to set a folder as "temporary" so that its contents are deleted after shutdown?

Tags: windows

I need to mark some folders on my C: and D: drives as temporary, so that all contents saved in them get deleted after shutdown.

How can I do that?

Comment: You should phrase that as a question and give us some additional information like which OS you are using... Obviously it is Windows so you could try a shutdown script.

Comment: Running a script on boot time will be much easier. Place the script in startup folder.

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://superuser.com/questions/338451/clear-the-temp-folder-on-shutdown or http://superuser.com/questions/211574/automatically-deleting-c-documents-and-settings-user-local-settings-temp?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're on Windows, write a script to delete the folders in question. You could also do this on start up to create the folder(s) (if applicable to your situation).

Open up gpedit.msc (local Policies) - > Computer Configuration -> Windows settings -> Scripts -> Shutdown / Startup -> Add

Comment: Also run that script on startup so that the folder gets deleted even if your computer crashes.

Answer (score 3):

The [gpedit.msc answer](https://superuser.com/a/571106/219873) worked for me in the past.  I even upvoted it.  I also tried [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) and [MoveOnBoot](http://emcosoftware.com/move-on-boot).  Both have the ability to delete the folder on next restart.  Unlocker can handle most deletes but my particular situation was too difficult for it.

Here's what worked for me.  It uses Task Scheduler to run the delete task at system startup.

1. Open Task Scheduler.  Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and run `control schedtasks`.
2. Create Task.

   1. General tab

      1. Provide a name
      2. Select `Run whether user is logged on or not`
      3. Check `Run with highest privileges`
      4. Configure for `Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2`
   2. Triggers tab

      1. Press `New...`
      2. Set `Begin the task` to `At startup`
      3. Press `OK`
   3. Actions tab

      1. Press `New...`
      2. Set `Program/script:` to `C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe`
      3. Set `Add arguments (optional):` to `/c rmdir /s /q C:\some_directory`
      4. Press `OK`
   4. Conditions tab

      1. Clear all check boxes
   5. Settings tab

      1. Check `Allow task to be run on demand`
      2. Check `Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed`
      3. Clear remaining check boxes
      4. Set `If the task is already running, then the following rule applies:` to `Run a new instance in parallel`
   6. Click `OK`